# Browser ignores table-layout:fixed

Tags: html, css, html-table

I fail to implement a fixed table layout. If a table cell has more content than would fit into it, the table is relayouted as if the table layout was set to auto.
Here is the HTML code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Table test</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<path here>" /> 
  </head>
  <body>
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th class="number">Number</th>
          <th class="name">Name</th>
          <th class="type">Type</th>
          <th class="comment">Comment</th>
          <th class="buttons"></th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>42</td>
          <td>This name is really long and is supposed to be truncated</td>
          <td>Normal</td>
          <td>I don't know what to say</td>
          <td><button>Edit...</button></td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

The CSS is

```
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  table-layout: fixed;
}

th {
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: left;
}

td {
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

tr {
  border-top: 1px solid #000000;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000000;
}

th.number {
  width: 6rem;
}

th.name {
  width: 15rem;
}

th.type {
  width: 17rem;
}

th.comment {
  width: 15rem;
}

th.buttons {
  width: 17rem;
}
```

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9pzc0r8v/). The problem is that the 2nd column ("name") is increased until the content fits. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set `width` on the `table` element, because the definition of [Fixed table layout](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/tables.html#fixed-table-layout) says: “The table's width may be specified explicitly with the 'width' property. A value of 'auto' (for both 'display: table' and 'display: inline-table') means use the automatic table layout algorithm. However, if the table is a block-level table ('display: table') in normal flow, a UA may (but does not have to) use the algorithm of 10.3.3 to compute a width and apply fixed table layout even if the specified width is 'auto'.” (Note that `auto` is the default value.)

This is awkward, but to get fixed layout, you need to add

```
table { width: calc(40rem + 10px); }
```

Here `40rem` is the sum of the widths you are setting for the columns, and `10px` accommodates the default padding in cells (`1px` on the left and right in each cell).

Older browsers don’t support the `calc` construct, but you are already taking risks by using the `rem` unit.

Comment: That is what I feared. I hoped, I could avoid to set a total width explicitly, if all columns had a width. (In that case the total width would be redundant.) My example above is extremely simplified, because the individual width each column is much more complicated and uses media queries. I hoped, the browser would be intelligent enough to figure out the total width by itself.